# How to get uid of currentUser after sign up in flutter firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I want to get the uid and display it on screen after a user signs up.

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.auth.currentUser.uid;
```

After the user signs up the uid is null and I cant display the uid. It works only when a user signs in but not when user signs up.
How can I show the uid just after user signs up?

**EDIT:**

This is the provider model

```
class UserModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  getUid() {
    final User user = auth.currentUser;
    return user.uid;
  }
}
```

I am creating the user in a separate file (auth_helper.dart)

```
class AuthHelper {
  static FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  static createAccountWithEmail({email, password}) async {
    final res = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
    email: email, password: password);
    final User user = res.user;

    return user;
  }
}
```

I want to save the User in my UserModel from inside the auth_helper.dart file above. How can I do so??

Answer (score 0):

You can get the signed up user's data after creating it. It will look like this:

```
  // Example code for registration.
  void _register() async {
    final User user = (await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: _emailController.text,
      password: _passwordController.text,
    ))
        .user;
    if (user != null) {
      setState(() {
        _success = true;
        _userEmail = user.email;
      });
    } else {
      _success = false;
    }
  }
```

You can check this official Github project of the [firebase_auth](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_auth/firebase_auth/example/lib/register_page.dart) package.

Comment: The createUser method is in a different file so I cant send data from it. Is there any other way?

Comment: Youı can send data from there. After creating that user, you will set it into an app state provider. Then you can access it from all of your files.

Comment: How can I access provider inside of a class?

Comment: Can you edit your question with your class or wherever you want to use that signed user?

Comment: Can you please check??